# issue Android 11 with SDK 28

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have a client who was using my application and it was working,
but since the new year, it's not working.
My app is target to SDK 28 and use the old library android.support and crash on start, does anyone have this issue ou know about it ?

Comment: Provide details of the crash for helping you.

Comment: th client just touch the app icon and have the crash screen

Comment: Make your client device as a developer device and install your app through "instant run" from android studio for logging enough information. If you can't get the client device then create an emulator(for API 30) and log the error. Because Log is only a tool to debug app.